# Generator for $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

Is the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated exclusively by $\langle 1,x\rangle$? Or has to be generated by more or less elements?
My intuition is that you can generate any of the "$x$'s" polynomials with just multiplying and adding $x$ to the equation but you need the "$1$" to generate the coefficient with degree $0$.

Comment: As a ring with unity, it is generated by $x$ alone. As a ring (not necessarily with unity) it is generated by $1,x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition would be correct. The only way to generate $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is by having 1 in your ideal. Similarly, you must have x in your ideal to generate all the polynomials.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've just read a powerful tool to prove that this specifically ring cannot be Principal; **from the Dummit Abstract Algebra:** Let $a,b \neq 0 \in R$. if $d$ is the unique generator for $R$ then the greatest common divisor is a power of $d$. However, when you use $[a = x \land b = x^2]$ or $[a = x \land b = 1]$ you see there're 2 generators 1 and x.